# Can one use Azure Kubernetes Service or Azure Service Fabric to deploy and manage on-prem kubernetes clusters?

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks, hybrid-cloud

I have a question about AKS and Service Fabric. Do both or either of these services have the ability to also manage on-prem kubernetes cluster/nodes? Or are Microsoft's managed kubernetes services only for Azure deployed kubernetes clusters?

I.e., we want a kubernetes implementation where a cluster or cluster(s) are distributed across a hybrid cloud.  I'm aware of some tools which can manage multi-cluster kubernetes from on-prem, but not sure about Azure services that can manage on-prem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no - AKS is limited to running in Azure. That being said - Microsoft has an additional option in preview for [Azure Arc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-arc/). This provides an additional management layer onto of Kubernetes that can exist in Azure, on premises and other clouds. It’s not cluster management and scheduling of pods, but allows for consistent governance and monitoring across multiple environments.

Hopefully that helps!